# WSO2 ESB timeout Endpoint error handling

Tags: wso2, esb

I have a simple proxy in WSO2 ESB, and sometimes backend service 
process request for a long time and I catch a timeout on the ESB.  I dont want to increase timeout, I just want to handle this error in sequence and send error message back.

But when endpoint is timed out I cant send payloaded message back

#### ESB log:

```
ERROR - ClientUtils The system cannot infer the transport information from the /services/restEventReaderSoap URL.
ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the /services/restEventReaderSoap URL.
    at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:81)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:115)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:482)`
```

#### Proxy config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="restEventReaderSoap"
   transports="https http"
   startOnLoad="true"
   trace="disable">
<description/>
<target>
  <inSequence>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="http://myserver/RestInformation" format="soap11">
              <timeout>
                 <duration>1000</duration>
                 <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
              </timeout>
           </address>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
  <faultSequence>
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
           <Send>
              <id>$1</id>
           </Send>
        </format>
        <args>
           <arg value="Error"/>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
     <send/>
  </faultSequence>
 </target>
</proxy>
```

Where is my error and what I have to do?

Comment: if change <payload> mediator to makefault in fault sequence, it will work well  <makefault version="soap11">
            <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  value="soap11Env:EdnpointTimeout"/>
            <reason value="timeout"/>
            <role/>
         </makefault>

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following in you fault handler :

```
<header action="remove" name="To" scope="default"/>
<property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check that your service url is correctly pointing towards your wso2 server.